# How to get radio button and calender control values in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have radio button and calender control in component and I am trying to get selected values of those.
When I select any radio button I am not getting its value in console. For calender control nothing is happening with no error in console. I have below code.

```
    statusHandler = (event) => {
        console.log("radio event",event.target);
        var key = event.target.name;
        console.log("radio key :", key);// can see key here
        var val = event.target.value;//not getting a value here.
        console.log("radio value :", val);
    }

handleChange = date => {
        var key = event.target.name;
        console.log("calender  key :", key);
        var val = event.target.value;//not getting a value here.
        console.log("calender value :", val);
    }

//render menthod code 
<DatePicker name={model.date} value={this.state.selectedDate} selected={this.state.startDate} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
<div className="some-class">
<input type="radio" className="radio" name={model.CODE} value={this.state.isLoan} onChange={this.statusHandler} />
<label htmlFor={model.CODE}>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" className="radio" name={model.CODE} onChange={this.statusHandler}  value={this.state.isLoan}/>
<label htmlFor={model.CODE}>No</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Those radio buttons are a little weird, you're swapping the value each time the state changes? (E.g. When it's not checked and becomes checked, the state for the "No" radio button will be "Yes", unless react can change it faster tan the event can fire, which it shouldn't be able to do)

Comment: @DBS. Sorry did not get you.

Comment: If the radio button for "Yes" is **not** checked (`checked={this.state.isLoan === "Yes"}`) then the value will be "No" (`value={this.state.isLoan}`). At the point where you change which is selected, the values are swapped (The "Yes" radio button has the value "No" when it it not checked)

Comment: I was not getting a value so I just got that line of code from google and tried. But its anyways not working and I have removed it now. Any suggestion for calender control issue. Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following code here I use Radio and showing selected value in alert. before running this code run the command like 
**yarn add @material-ui/core**

here is the code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import FormLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormLabel";
import RadioGroup from "@material-ui/core/RadioGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import Radio from "@material-ui/core/Radio";

function RadioExample(props) {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState('female');

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setValue(event.target.value);
        alert(event.target.value);
    };
    return (
        <FormControl component="fieldset">
            <FormLabel component="legend">Gender</FormLabel>
            <RadioGroup aria-label="gender" name="gender1" value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
                <FormControlLabel value="female" control={<Radio/>} label="Female"/>
                <FormControlLabel value="male" control={<Radio/>} label="Male"/>
                <FormControlLabel value="other" control={<Radio/>} label="Other"/>
            </RadioGroup>
        </FormControl>
    );
}
export default RadioExample;
```